# O(log(A)) + O(log(B)) = O(log(A * B))?

Tags: big-o, complexity-theory

This is true:

```
log(A) + log(B) = log(A * B)    [0]
```

Is this also true?

```
O(log(A)) + O(log(B)) = O(log(A * B)) [1]
```

From what I understand

`O(f(n)) + O(g(n)) = max( O(f(n)), O(g(n)) ) [2]`

or in other words - if one function grows asymptotically faster than the other then only that function is relevant to the big O notation. So maybe this equation is true instead?

```
O(log(A)) + O(log(B)) = max( O(log(A), O(log(B)) ) [3]
```

Comment: Equation [3] is 'true' (both [1] and [3] are mathematically equivalent but [3] is arguably more useful).

Answer (score 2):

`O` is linear.

Therefore `O(a) + O(b) = O(a + b)`.

So `O(log(A)) + O(log(B)) = O(log(A) + log(B)) = O(log(A * B))`

---

Concerning `[3]`, you are right.

`if m = O(n) then O(n + m) = O(2n) = 2 O(n) = O(n) (2 is a constant)`

Answer (score 1):

This is always true : `O(X + Y) = O(X) + O(Y)`

Also complexity is not as precious as algebra. It means, if something is equal in algebra it must be equal in complexity. (of course, if something is equal in complexity it does not have to be equal in algebra)

Answer (score 0):

[1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultrametric_space#Formal_definition) is true. This is the proof, let c_1 and c_2 be the constants which you get by the definition of the Big-O of a function. So you have:

```
O(log(A)) + O(log(B))  
= c_1*log(A) + c_2*log(B)
<= c*log(A) + c*log(B)  where c=max{c_1,c_2}
= c*(log(A)+log(B))
= O(log(A*B))
```

With the same logic, you can see that [3] is correct, so you have:

```
   O(log(A)) + O(log(B)) 
    = c_1*log(A) + c_2*log(B) [5]
```

So suppose that log(A) is the maximum of log(A) and log(B), you get that the previous equation [5] is:

```
    <= c_1*log(A) + c_2*log(A)
    = (c_1+c2)*log(A)
    = O(log(A)) 
    = O(max(log(A), log(B)))
```

Which can be simplified to:

```
    = max(O(log(A)), O(log(B)) )
```